# Total Factorization

Tags: code-golf, number

## The challenge

Given positive integer input `n` (`n>1`), calculate the array of unique factorizations of `n`, not including `1`. Order does not matter.

### Test cases

```
2 => [[2]]
3 => [[3]]
4 => [[4],[2,2]]
5 => [[5]]
6 => [[6],[2,3]]
7 => [[7]]
8 => [[8],[2,2,2],[2,4]]
9 => [[9],[3,3]]
10 => [[10],[2,5]]
11 => [[11]]
12 => [[12],[3,4],[3,2,2],[2,6]]
```

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so lowest byte count wins!

Comment: Shouldn't 8 have [2, 4]?

Comment: Yeah, I was dumb. It should also have [2,2,2]

Comment: Oddly enough this is quite useful for solving a kenken puzzle

Comment: I never saw the problem this was a duplicate of, but it still isn't an exact duplicate: this doesn't require `1`, but it **IS** close enough to be a dupe, now that I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ÆfŒṖP€€Ṣ€Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9rRSQ93Tgt41LQGiB7uXAQkA////28BAA)

```
ÆfŒṖP€€Ṣ€Q
Æf          - prime factorization
  ŒṖ        - all partitions
    P€€     - Product of each sub-partition
       Ṣ€   - Sort each
         Q  - Remove duplicates
```

Comment: Accepted, since the post is closed anyways.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <strike>9</strike> 14 bytes

```
{mS*Mds./M.pP
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BmS%2aMd.%2FP&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A12&debug=0)

#### How it works

```
{mS*Mds./M.pP
            P    Prime factorization of [the input]
          .p     All permutations of the prime factorization
       ./M       All partitions of each permutation
      s          Flattened by one level
 m               For each partition:
   *Md               Take the product of each piece
  S                  Sort the products
{                De-duplicate.
```

Comment: I don't grok Pyth, could you provide an explanation?

Comment: @Zacharý Added.

Comment: This fails on the input `30`, since Pyth's `./` only gives sequential partitions. (`[3, 10]` is absent). I should add something that works like this.

Comment: @isaacg Aw, that's unfortunate. Fixed for 5 bytes.